# not sure how to breathe life into mate 8 64gb dual sim variant

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, bootloader

I'm at a loss here, i have nougat on my mate mate 8 but i completely forgot that you had to root nougat in a particular way. Anyway, i don't have access to erecovery, power+volUPvolDown doesn't work and i can't get access to fastboot. The only thing i do get is power to the screen and my 'your phone is unlocked and can't be trusted blah blah' message.

I need to flash a recovery.img, system.img and any other relevant img. How can i do this with the phone in this state?

Comment: Flash the stock rom by searching it from Google for your device and if you don't know how to flash rom search on YouTube.

Comment: 1. Turn off your phone - 2. connect a USB Cable to PC - 3. Press and **hold** Volume Down - 4. Plug in the USB cable to phone - 5. `fastboot boot twrp-3.3.1-0-next.img` - 6. flash ROM

Comment: when i do that, the huawei logo flashes very briefly, then it flashes again very briefly and then its back to the 'your phone has been unlocked and cant be trusted' screen

Comment: if you are willing to pay you can flash with third party tools via COM port. you need to short circuit the test point https://easy-firmware.com/media/articles/large/2018/08/17/237829-1534544261.jpg and install the Huawei USB COM 1.0 drivers https://sigmakey.com/nfs/content/6104/file/HUAWEI_USB_COM_1.0_driver.zip but i would not recommend this because your phone seems still intact (only has dm-verity locked)

Comment: instead i would try everything you can do to figure out how to enter fastboot mode. fastboot is the best option to repair things. once you have entered fastboot, do not accidentally re-lock bootloader by flashing stock ROM, otherwise you have to pay for unlock code https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRfY7NM-s6I

Comment: I already have unlock code. Not worried about re rooting if I have to. Yes...I think fastboot is the safest bet for now. My worst case scenario is taking the phone to a repair shop where I might have to part with $100. It's starting to sound like it's worth it if I'm honest because no matter what I do...I cannot get access to fast boot. Even my Linux machine can't pick up any raw hardware so for now my ph is still not visible on any software

Comment: can you disconnect the battery, then try enter fastboot mode again (like he did in Video)? if still no fastboot, try the test point method and see if it connects

Comment: whats the test point method?? when you say disconnect the battery do you mean physically open the phone and disconnect battery? If that's what you mean then no is my answer to that one.